# Query takes too long to query with OR clause but their parts are very quick

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

I am querying two tables, each with ~1M rows indexed by their IDs, using the following query:

```
SELECT t.* FROM transactions t
INNER JOIN integration it ON it.id_trans = t.id_trans
WHERE t.id_trans = '5440073'
OR it.id_integration = '439580587'
```

This query takes about 30s. But

```
SELECT ... WHERE t.id_trans = '5440073'
```

takes less than 100ms and

```
SELECT ... WHERE it.id_integration = '439580587'
```

also takes less than 100ms. Even

```
SELECT ... WHERE t.id_trans = '5440073'
UNION
SELECT ... WHERE it.id_integration = '439580587'
```

takes less then 100ms

Why does the `OR` clause take so much time if the parts are so fast?

What should I do to improve the performance of this query?

Comment: Use UNION of 2 queries with simple conditions instead of OR in WHERE.

Answer (score 0):

Using `UNION` is the way to speed up the query.  A discussion of "why"...

The likely way of performing the query:  Do the `JOIN`, *then* scan the entire intermediate table, checking each row for the `WHERE` expression.  That is, check each row for both conditions in the `OR`.  This is slow because if reads the entire table.

But, let's look at a simple optimization:

```
SELECT  t.*
    FROM  transactions t
    INNER JOIN  integration it  ON it.id_trans = t.id_trans
    WHERE it.id_trans = '5440073'   -- note change from `t` to `it`
      OR  it.id_integration = '439580587'
```

Normally, the Optimizer will notice that `id_trans` could come from either table.  If it does so, then it would do the transformation I show above.  At that point, the Optimizer would decide to look into `it` first because all the filtering is there.

Here's a better way to phrase the query:

```
SELECT  t.*
    FROM  integration it  ON it.id_trans = t.id_trans
    JOIN  transactions t  USING(id_trans)
    WHERE    id_trans = '5440073'
      OR  it.id_integration = '439580587'
```

This is only a syntax change, but it better hints that `id_trans` is the same between the tables, and it hints that `it` is the 'first' table to look at.

Now, let me discussion the options for optimizing

```
    FROM  integration
    WHERE    id_trans = '5440073'
      OR     id_integration = '439580587'
```

(Note:  After that is done, the execution will reach over to `t` to get `t.*` for delivering the results.)

Plan A:  Scan the entire table, checking each row for the `WHERE` expression.  That is, check each row for both conditions in the `OR`.  This is slow because if reads the entire table.

Plan B:  `INDEX(id_trans, id_integration)` (in either order).  This improves on Plan A only in scanning the entire index; the presumption is that the index is smaller than the table, hence a little faster to scan.  Even in the final query, it will be considered a "covering index" (as indicated by "Using index" in the `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`).

Plan C:  Explicit `UNION`, plus `INDEX(id_trans), INDEX(id_integration)`.  The Optimizer will use one index for each part of the `UNION`.  There is, still, some overhead of putting together the two temp tables that come out of the `UNION`, then de-dupping.  If the dedupping is not needed, then say `UNION ALL` as a further optimization.

Plan D:  The same indexes as in Plan C.  In this case, the Optimizer *may* use "Index merge (union)" (again, see `EXPLAIN`).  This is like doing the `UNION` under the covers.